# Как создать простой concept на ограничение типов по списку?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20, concept

Попытался написать свой первый концепт и застрял на непонятной для меня ошибке.
Вот код:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename Type>
concept String =  std::is_same_v<Type,const char*>
               || std::is_same_v<Type,std::string>;

template<String Type>
void function(Type&& string)
{
    std::forward<Type>(string);
}

int main()
{
    std::string string{"7"};
    function(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод:

> error: use of function 'void function(Type) [with Type =
> std::__cxx11::basic_string]' with unsatisfied constraints

Я прочитал про `requires`, но не понимаю, как его применить в данном случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, получилось вот так:

```
#include <string>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Type>
concept String =  std::same_as<std::remove_cvref<Type>,std::string>;

template<String Type>
void function(Type&& string)
{
    std::forward<Type>(string);
}

int main()
{
    std::string string1{"7"};
    const std::string string2{"7"};
    function(string1);
    function(string2);
    function(std::string{"7"});
    return 0;
}
```

Правда, все равно, по-хорошему придется для `const char*` делать специализацию.

Comment: Лучше `std::same_as` (концепт) вместо `std::is_same_v`, это во-первых. А во-вторых, чтобы не писать три раза `std::string` с разным набором `&` и `const`, лучше сделать `std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>, std::string>`.